# Scrapy - NameError: global name 'logger' is not defined

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapy-middleware

I am trying to modify Scrapy retry a little bit by modifying the middleware. I use this middleware:

```
class Retry500Middleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def _retry(self, request, reason, spider):
        retries = request.meta.get('retry_times', 0) + 1

        if retries <= self.max_retry_times:
            logger.debug("Retrying %(request)s (failed %(retries)d times): %(reason)s",
                         {'request': request, 'retries': retries, 'reason': reason},
                         extra={'spider': spider})
            retryreq = request.copy()
            retryreq.meta['retry_times'] = retries
            retryreq.meta['download_timeout'] = 600
            retryreq.dont_filter = True
            retryreq.priority = request.priority + self.priority_adjust
            return retryreq
        else:
            logger.error("Gave up retrying %(request)s (failed %(retries)d times): %(reason)s",
                         {'request': request, 'retries': retries, 'reason': reason},
                         extra={'spider': spider})
```

Then I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 53, in process_response
    spider=spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py", line 54, in process_response
    return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
  File "/home/<user_name>/<project_folder>/<project_name>/<project_name>/middlewares.py", line 48, in _retry
    logger.debug("Retrying %(request)s (failed %(retries)d times): %(reason)s",
NameError: global name 'logger' is not defined
2018-08-15 14:01:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I used it in my machine and the middleware works just fine. What should I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I use this code instead

```
import logging
logging.log(logging.ERROR, "Gave up retrying %(request)s (failed %(retries)d times): %(reason)s",
                         {'request': request, 'retries': retries, 'reason': reason},
                         extra={'spider': spider})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

You can either put a self.logger = logging.getLogger(**name**) in your Generic.**init**() function, or define a global logger after importing the logging. Refer to this answer :

[NameError: global name 'logger' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058121/nameerror-global-name-logger-is-not-defined)